# Containerized process terminated by signal 119

Tags: sql, performance, kubernetes, error-handling, kubernetes-pod

When we are trying to extract a large table from a sql server, we are getting an error:

```
Containerized process terminated by signal 119.
```

As per my understanding, kubernetes containers have a limit of how many GB is allocated to memory for each POD.
So suppose if we have a limitation on memory and the table size is expected to be larger then what is the option we have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A Container can exceed its memory request if the Node has memory available. But a Container is not allowed to use more than its memory limit. If a Container allocates more memory than its limit, the Container becomes a candidate for termination. If the Container continues to consume memory beyond its limit, the Container is terminated. If a terminated Container can be restarted, the kubelet restarts it, as with any other type of runtime failure.
> <sup>[[source](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-memory-resource/#exceed-a-container-s-memory-limit)]</sup>

There are two possible reasons:

- Your container exceeds it's memory limits set in `spec.containers[].resources.limits.memory` field; or
- Your container exceeds node available memory.

In the first case you can increase memory limit by changing `spec.containers[].resources.limits.memory` value.

In the second case you can either increase node's resources or make sure the pod is being scheduled on a node with more available memory.

Comment: @SurajTripathi, please remember to [react to answers for your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). That way we know if the answers were helpful and other community members could also benefit from them. Try to [accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) that is the final solution for your issue, upvote answers that are helpful and comment on those which could be improved or require additional attention.